# Accessing to global variable from PHP static class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to refractor my code by using static methods on models, but I lost the ability to get the Database object.

```
<?php
$Database = new PDO(.....);
class MyModel{
    public static function getSomething(){
       $test = $Database->somePDOStuff(..);
       ...
    }
}
echo MyModel::getSomething();
?>
```

That's an a very basic example, but here MyModel doesn't know $Database.

Any idea on how to let them know each other?

Comment: injecting the `$database`to the function seem a good idea. Have you thought about making your database class a static class? There are ways to have it initialize the connection the first time it is called (statically) and reuse it every further calls

Comment: this has nothing to do wit OOP nor with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Database` is out of scope inside your class and function.  Consider changing your code to something more like this(below).  You send in the `PDO` object to the function so it has access to it.

```
<?php
$Database = new PDO(.....);
class MyModel{
    public static function getSomething(PDO $pdo){
       $test = $pdo->somePDOStuff(..);
       ...
    }
}
echo MyModel::getSomething($Database);
?>
```

Here's another solution.  Set a static PDO object inside `MyModel`.  I would not advise using this solution as it's pretty messy.  Look at the last solution which is more in the direction i'd go

```
<?php
    $Database = new PDO(.....);
    class MyModel{
        public static $pdo;
        public static function getSomething(){
           $test = self::$pdo->somePDOStuff(..);
           ...
        }
    }
    MyModel::$pdo = $Database;
    echo MyModel::getSomething();
?>
```

Consider making your class `MyModel` include a `PDO` object that's created in the constructor.

```
<?php
    class MyModel{
        private $pdo;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->setPdo(new PDO(.....));
        }
        public static function getSomething(){
           $instance = new self();
           $test = $instance->getPdo()->somePDOStuff(..);
           ...
        }
        public function setPdo(PDO $pdo) {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }
        public function getPdo() {
            return $this->pdo;
        }
    }
    echo MyModel::getSomething();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `global` in your class method

```
   public static function getSomething(){

       global $Database;
       $test = $Database->somePDOStuff(..);
       //.... 
  }
```

However, I'd look at avoiding this practice.  Why not make $dabase a static variable of a Database class or th MyModel class?

Even better, you could set it with some good old injection by passing it into the funciton like:

```
  echo MyModel::getSomething($Database);
```

Comment: using a `global $Database` won't clean up the code. the $Database variable contains a dynamic object and couldn't be static